# What distinguishes these LAPACK programmes? One compiles, the other does not

Tags: c, gcc, lapack

I have two programmes using the LAPACK routine `dgeev` in C. One appears to be working, the other does not compile claiming undefined reference to `dgeev`. I seek to understand why.

The first code below - called mamapack.c - produces sensible results when compiled and run like this:

> ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$ gcc -o mamapack mamapack.c -L/usr/local/lib -llapack -lblas && ./mamapack

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

//...........................................................................
void dgeTranspose( double *Transposed, double *M ,int n) {
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      Transposed[i+n*j] = M[i*n+j];
}
//...........................................................................
//  MatrixComplexEigensystem: computes the eigenvectors and eigenValues of input matrix A
//  The eigenvectors are stored in columns
//............................................................................
void MatrixComplexEigensystem( double *eigenvectorsVR, double *eigenvaluesW, double *A, int N) {
  int i;
  double *AT = (double *) malloc( N*N*sizeof(double ) );
  dgeTranspose( AT, A , N);
  char JOBVL ='N';   // Compute Right eigenvectors
  char JOBVR ='V';   // Do not compute Left eigenvectors
  double VL[1];
  int LDVL = 1; 
  int LDVR = N;
  int LWORK = 4*N; 
  double *WORK =  (double *)malloc( LWORK*sizeof(double));   
  double *RWORK = (double *)malloc( 2*N*sizeof(double));
  int INFO;
  double *eigenvaluesWR =eigenvaluesW;
  double *eigenvaluesWI = eigenvaluesW + N;
  dgeev_( &JOBVL, &JOBVR, &N, AT ,  &N,
       eigenvaluesWR, eigenvaluesWI,
       VL, &LDVL, 
       eigenvectorsVR, &LDVR, 
       WORK, &LWORK, &INFO );
  printf("\nping1\n");

  dgeTranspose( AT, eigenvectorsVR , N);

  for(i=0;i<N*N;i++) eigenvectorsVR[i]=AT[i];

  free(WORK);
  free(RWORK);
  free(AT);
}

int main() {
  int i,j;
  const int N = 3;
  double A[] = { 1. , 0. ,  0. , 0. , 1., 0. , 0., 0., 1.};
  double eigenVectors[N*N];
  double eigenValues[2*N];

  MatrixComplexEigensystem( eigenVectors, eigenValues, A, N);

  printf("\nEigenvectors\n");

  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++) printf("%e ", eigenVectors[i*N + j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("\nEigenvalues \n");
  for(i=0;i<N;i++) printf("%e ",  eigenValues[i] );
  printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------\n"); 

  return 0;
}
```

Then I ran another code that I called lapack1.c, which is just the official "Example program in C" from this documentation: https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgeev.htm
(I dare not post it separately due to potential copyright restrictions)

> ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$ gcc -o lapack1 lapack1.c
>   -L/usr/local/lib -llapack -lblas && ./lapack1

produces

> tmp/cciRzQru.o: In function `main': lapack1.c:(.text+0xf3): undefined
>   reference to`dgeev' lapack1.c:(.text+0x1b6): undefined reference to
>   `dgeev' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: That is a message from the linker, not the compiler. Apparently you missed lining a library or object file. Maybe a missing package whichinclude a lib with "dgeev" (called from dgeTranspose()?) symbol? (No idea what that would be). Sidenote; do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc()` And you shoul dnot use uppercase for variables. These are commonly used for constants and are missleading here.

Comment: @Olaf 49 Sorry, I was unsure, as I cannot distinguish them and I do not understand this well. What should I investigate? Why does the other programme run using dgeev?

Comment: The blonde on the phone to the doctor: "Doctor, I have some itching on this side." The doctor: "So please lift your shirt and show me."

Comment: @Olaf 49 double face ;)

Comment: I don't understand what that means. Cultural references are problematic in an international forum.

Comment: I meant, what might seem to start as a joke about blondes, just turned into one about doctors. Actually the phrase probably only works in my mother tongue (with the french pronounciation). I am new to this community. I fear the moderators may punish us for abuse of the comment section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79059/discussion-between-ludi-and-olaf).

Comment: The joke was actually related to your question and a friendly hint! To understand, you need to know that once phones had no camera, so there was only audio (sometime B.C.). Now think about that!

Comment: @Olaf 49 That I did perceive. So I understood the joke as suggesting the doctor was even more clueless than the patient, asking her to show herself on an analogue phone...

Comment: ehm.. no, it was not. It was actually an analogy: You ask about something I would have to know (see) your environment, for instance what is installed in your /ur/local/lib/ and where that missing symbol would be. No camera -understand now? Point is, the blonde is asking something which obviously cannot be remotely answered as there is information missing. However, you might better continue with John's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your function names carefully.  The linker is complaining about an undefined reference to function `dgeev()`.  The working code is calling a different function, named `dgeev_()`.

Compiling with the option -D as follows:

> ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$ gcc -Ddgeev=dgeev_ -o lapack1
>   lapack1.c -L/usr/local/lib -llapack -lblas && ./lapack1

Will indeed work.

Comment: Apologies. I saw that. But it is official example code. I did not expect having to change anything inside.

Comment: But of course you are right. That is a difference. Perhaps the question then becomes, how should the code be compiled, if not with the same options as the other one.

Comment: You are using the Fortran interface to LAPACK.  The example code may assume a LAPACK implementation compiled with a toolchain that does not mangle Fortran function names.  Your installed library, on the other hand, was built with a toolchain that *does* mangle Fortran function names, which is not unusual.  GFortran does that, for sure.

Comment: You should call functions via their actual names.  If you don't want to change the C code, then use a preprocessor macro to correct the relevant function name(s) (this can be defined on the command line, if necessary).